# Difference between schema in oracle and mysql

Tags: mysql, oracle, schema

In the Oracle database, a user owns a single schema. What about MySQL? Is there something like a user owning a single schema in MySQL too? I read some documentation of schema on MySQL, it seems the concepts are very different in MySQL and Oracle databases. Is there any relation between schema in MySQL and Oracle?